# Not found the code for a map R animation

Tags: r, mapping, animation, animatedmarker

I tried to make an animated map in R with tmap package, like here
https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html#animated-maps

I tried to find the code for the animated map presented in section [8.3 Animated maps] from the link but I have not find it. 
Where is the code for this map?

Comment: https://github.com/Robinlovelace/geocompr/blob/master/code/08-urban-animation.R
https://github.com/Robinlovelace/geocompr/blob/master/code/08-usboundaries.R
Links bellow are not available,
any one could help with a working link to the file

Answer (score 1):

You can find the code from each chapter at https://github.com/Robinlovelace/geocompr/tree/master/code/chapters.
The code for the first animation is at https://github.com/Robinlovelace/geocompr/blob/master/code/08-urban-animation.R, and for the second one at https://github.com/Robinlovelace/geocompr/blob/master/code/08-usboundaries.R.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I found the code!